Need an excel formula to identify duplicates yet provide a unique count among those duplicates
Basically, I've got excel lists of registrants for a serires of online webinars and we'd like to see how many people have registered for more than one event using the email addresses as the unique identifier.
The columns are first name, last name, email address, and registration time.
I had initally been adding a column titled "Repeat?" and after sorting by email, manually added a "1" next to the first instance of a repeat email address then summed that column to get a count of how many people repeatedly registered.
That method is both subject to human error and too time consuming to be sustainable as we approach 1,000 entries.
Any solutions are welcome!

Does your version of Excel support the UNIQUE formula?

There are some examples similar to this question please check. That might give you some insight on how to do it. Refer1 , Refer2, Refer3, Refer4, Refer5

I would make a copy of all the email addresses in a separate column, then use "remove duplicates" or unique() to get a list then apply countif() and any greater than 1 has a duplicate.

You can use the formula =COUNTIF(C:C,C2) to get the count of email address having multiple occurrences. Please let me know if you any question on the formula.

If your version of Excel supports the UNIQUE function (Added in Excel 2021), then you can use =COUNTA(UNIQUE(C:C)) to count the Unique values in Columns C.  (You may need to subtract 1 for the header)
Alternatively, you can use something like =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(C:C, C:C), 0)) — somewhat slower/less effective, so you may want to limit the cells to the active range (e.g. =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(C$1:C$100, C$1:C$100),0)) / =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(C1:INDEX(C:C, COUNTA(C:C)), C1:INDEX(C:C, COUNTA(C:C))), 0))), but it works in older versions of Excel.
To identify how many times an Email Address appears, use COUNTIF (=COUNTIF(C:C,C2)).  To identify how many times it has already appeared (i.e. Subsequent duplicates, but not the First occurrence), limit the range and Lock the start row (=COUNTIF(C$1:C2, C2)), then fill the formula down
